# JSON file replaces HTML tags

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to parse my JSON file which contains kay-value pairs and replace tags in my HTML.

So the API gets a JSON file e.g.:

```
{
  "myValue1": "value1",
  "myValue2": "value2",
  "myValue3": "value3",
}
```

and I get a HTML template from DB like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="description" content="description">

<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/print.css" />

<style>
    body {background:#e3e3e3;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
      <p style="color: red;">{{myValue1}}</p>
      <p>{{myValue2}}</p>
      <p>{{myValue3}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I would like to replace all tags from JSON file to HTML file and the result should looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="description" content="description">

<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/print.css" />

<style>
    body {background:#e3e3e3;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
      <p style="color: red;">value1</p>
      <p>value2</p>
      <p>value3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The template should be replaceable and it is stored in DB. 
How can I do this in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the JSON data and use that result for replacing.

Assume this is your JSON data:

```
var json = @"{""myValue1"":""value1"",""myValue2"":""value2"",""myValue3"":""value3""}";
```

And assume this is your HTML template:

```
var template = "&lt;html&gt;.......&lt;/html&gt;";
```

Now deserialize this JSON into a new `Dictionary<string, string>` dictionary object using `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Now you can replace the tags in template like this:

```
foreach(var item in dictionary) {
    var key = "{{" + item.Key + "}}";
    var value = item.Value;
    template = template.Replace(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using tags like `{{myValue1}}`, you can specify an **id** for the element which needs to be changed. ie.

```
<p style="color: red;" id="myValue1"></p>
<p id="myValue2"></p>
<p id="myValue3"></p>
```

In your javascript, search for the element where the key in the JSON object matches the id of the element and set the value.

```
var json = {
  "myValue1": "value1",
  "myValue2": "value2",
  "myValue3": "value3",
};

for(var key in json) {
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var element = document.getElementById(key);
    if(element != null){
      element.innerHTML = json[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Check it out in codepen - https://codepen.io/gswe/pen/ybBObP

Comment: This is a .NET question. Unless you propose that the user send the JSON values to the browser and have Javascript replace elements. Which is the opposite of what any Javascript framework does. If you send the data to the browser, why not use *data binding*?